# Web App Script - How to pull value from question to be used in search to populate another question?

Tags: javascript, search, google-apps-script

Here is my current [script](https://script.google.com/d/1kjupGGI7Z0zhlzPzIVft1dr2WLPfJ5--WPgx5i9GB0AQ_cQXcQNrB5wD/edit?usp=sharing) and attached [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evNXXgFITrdNwsSdGXmprgzti74AQy03dg0igP5nT0I/edit?usp=sharing).

I have been able to successfully find the index value with function getColumnIndex(label) and then return that function into function getColumnValues(index) to pull all the rows in that specific column. I can't seem to use the input field from the autocomplete question id="courseCode" Enter Course Code as the search string to be used in the function getExpectations(); to populate the HTML page question id="expectations" as a multi selection question.

It works if I manually add the search string text to return the column rows. I would like to take the first 4 characters of the input field id="courseCode" Enter Course Code (3 letter followed by a number) as the search string to determine what selection options will populate the  id="expectations" question.

I am a bit confused with calling back functions within another function and when and how to use a parameter/condition to pass through the function.

I hope this is enough information to solve my script error. Thanks in advance for this concern. Take care.

Added the following lines of code to get all options selected in the multi-selection Course Expectations question.

```
function collectForm(){
    var submission = {};
    // gets you the values for all id="specific_names"

    submission.grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
    submission.courseCode = document.getElementById("courseCode").value;

    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedExpectations');
    var selection = ' ';
      for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (list[i].checked === true) {
        selection += list[i].value + ", ";
        }
      }

    submission.expectations = selection;

    google.script.run.userClicked(submission);
 }
```

Comment: Please share your codes here.

Comment: Please post your scripts in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In short

You need something like this

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} code
 */
function getExpectations2(code) {
  var patt = new RegExp(code.slice(0, 5), 'i');
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '1evNXXgFITrdNwsSdGXmprgzti74AQy03dg0igP5nT0I'
  )
    .getSheetByName('expectations')
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  var colIndex = data[0].reduce(function(p, c, i) {
    return patt.test(c) ? i : p;
  }, -1);
  return colIndex === -1
    ? []
    : data
        .slice(1)
        .filter(function(row) {
          return row[colIndex] !== '';
        })
        .map(function(row) {
          return row[colIndex];
        });
}
```

`getExpectations2` - returns a column by code as a list.

Also you have to update your `listExpectations`

```
  function listExpectations(listLabels) {
    console.log(listLabels);
    const elm = document.getElementById('expectations');
    const label = listLabels
      .map(row => `<option value="${row}">${row}</option>`)
      .join('');

    elm.innerHTML =
      '<option disabled selected>Select expectations not met</option>' + label;
    setTimeout(() => M.FormSelect.init(elm), 0);
  }
```

Of course you need bind all of them

```
  function populateCodes(codes) {
    var autocomplete = document.getElementById('courseCode');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, {
      data: codes,
      onAutocomplete: onAutocompleteCourseCode,
    });
  }
```

Where `onAutocompleteCourseCode` is

```
  const onAutocompleteCourseCode = courseCode => {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(listExpectations)
      .getExpectations2(courseCode);
  };
```

[image]

Comment: appreciate your detailed response @contributorpw - slight improvement to make question a multi-select option on line 53 of the page.html add multiple <select id="expectations" name="selectedExpectations" multiple>. However, it is not submitting the mult-selected responses to the form but the other data does transfer?

Comment: @Maicol add `submission.expectations = M.FormSelect.getInstance(document.getElementById('expectations')).getSelectedValues().join('; ');` and mark my answer as the best. The full snippet https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/webapp/materializecss_form_to_sheet/page-js.html#L25-L29

Comment: thank you for solving the issue. It works perfectly. I changed ,join(';'); to .join(('\n') instead to make it easier to read the multiple selections. I hope I marked your answer as the best correctly? Take care I appreciate it.